# Capturing remote output locally in Mac Terminal

Tags: linux, mac, ssh, terminal.app

I want local programmatic access to ssh output in Mac Terminal.

First, I tried redirecting the output of each command to a file. The file was perfect, but of course it was on the remote server, and an sftp for each command output seemed a little... heavy.

Next, I tried to Applescript Terminal, but it only gives access to the currently visible text in a tab (i.e. if half the output has already scrolled out of sight, it doesn't get returned - useless).

Last, I tried piping ssh to tee (e.g. ssh user@host | tee output.txt). This almost worked. I have the output in a local file, but there are a lot of unwanted characters mixed in. For example, every time I hit backspace, there's a ^H in the file. There's also text like "[0m[K" which is harder to get rid of.

How do I cleanly get this ssh output locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`script`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/freebsd/1/script/) to make a typescript of terminal session.

Then use `sed` to sanitise it.

E.g;

```
% script mysession

% ssh user@host

[some stuff]

% exit
Script done, output file is mysession

% sed -e '
s/'`echo "\033"`'\[[[:digit:]]*\(;[[:digit:]]*\)*[[:alpha:]]//g; # ANSI Escape sequences (perhaps over-generalised)
s/[^[:print:]]//g; # Non-printable
' mysession > mysession.txt
```

You should now be able to read `mysession.txt` without the [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) and other non-printable characters.

This could be enhanced to delete the character before a <kbd>^H</kbd>, *et cetera*, but you specified that you didn't want that.

Comment: I modified your ANSI Escape regex to start with a non-printable because it was stripping other things too. I think if you apply the change we have a solution: s/[^[:print:]]\[[[:digit:]]*\(;[[:digit:]]*\)*[[:alpha:]]//g;

Comment: I think that regular expression is probably a little too loose, but if it works for you, it works for you!

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same thing, but I'll use it until it hurts :)

Comment: Plus, I don't know what else to do because it doesn't work without it, and mac's sed doesn't seem to let you specify specific ASCII does in the regex. I really need to specify 027 (ESC), but it doesn't seem possible

Comment: @Sean DeNigris: Hmmm... BSD's `sed` does seem to struggle with those. I've updated my command for you.

Answer (score 1):

A very basic solution to clean the output would be the following:

```
sed 's/[\000-\037]^M/ /g' output.txt
```

I don't know however how to get that back into a file. For example, given the file

```
[~] # ls /
[1;34mbin[0m/         [1;36mhome[0m@        [1;34mlost+found[0m/  [1;36mphp.ini[0m@     [1;34msbin[0m/        [1;34msys[0m/         [1;34mvar[0m/
[1;34mdev[0m/         [1;34mlib[0m/         [1;34mmnt[0m/         [1;34mproc[0m/        [1;34mshare[0m/       [1;34mtmp[0m/
[1;34metc[0m/         [1;36mlinuxrc[0m@     [1;34mopt[0m/         [1;34mroot[0m/        [0;0mstunnel.pid[0m  [1;36musr[0m@
```

this results in the following being output:

```
[~] # ls /
bin/         home@        lost+found/  php.ini@     sbin/        sys/         var/
dev/         lib/         mnt/         proc/        share/       tmp/
etc/         linuxrc@     opt/         root/        stunnel.pid  usr@
```

---

You can also log a session with `script`. So whenever you enter the SSH session, first type

```
script output.txt
```

which will then open a new shell and log all your actions without needing to redirect output or anything. When you're finished, just `exit` the shell. If the remove SSH server doesn't have `script`, you can run it from OS X, but then the SSH output will be garbled again.

Comment: I think that it only appears to be helping because it's viewed in the terminal, which correctly displays them. If I redirect your solution  into a file, it contains the same mess.

Comment: I know, that's why I said it wasn't perfectly working :)